# Is a submodule uniquely determined by its sum and intersection with a fixed submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

It is true or false that if $M_1,M_2,M_3$ are submodules of a module $M$ over a commutative ring with identity which satisfy the relations $M_1 + M_3=M_2+M_3$ and $M_1\cap M_3=M_2\cap M_3$ then necessarily $M_1=M_2$?

Can you give me a little hint to prove this result if it's true, or to find a counterexample if it is false? I tried to find a counterexample but the most obvious cases all lead to the final equality, so I am no more sure that the result is false. On the other hand, apart from the obvious cases, it seems difficult to prove this result in more complicated cases.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Think about lines in $\mathbf{R}^2$ to see that it's false.

Comment: I think I have obtained the counterexample: if I take in $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ $M_1=\text{span}\{e_1\}, M_2=\text{span}\{e_2\}, M_3=\text{span}\{e_1 + e_2\}$ I have $M_1+M_3=M_2+M_3=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M_1\cap M_3=M_2 \cap M_3=\{0\}$. Is it right?

Comment: Diogenes: exactly! A bit more generally, take the $M_i$ to be any three distinct 1-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: @Diogenes- Can you rewrite your comment as answer so this question wont remain unanswered?

Comment: @user52045 - Ok. It's funny that when I was writing the comment as an answer, mathstackexchange suggested me to write it as a comment, not as an answer, and now you're telling me to do exactly the contrary :) But you're right, I'll do it immediately, thanks.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I didn't have such a simple idea... (perhaps the reason is that I am not so good as a student of mathematics... :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the useful hint of Asal Beag Dubh, here is a counterexample which proves that the result is false.

In $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ take $M_1=\text{span}\{e_1\},M_2=\text{span}\{e_2\},M_3=\text{span}\{e_1+e_2\}$, where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the canonical basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then you have $M_1+M_3=M_2+M_3=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M_1\cap M_3=M_2\cap M_3=\{0\}$. But obviously $M_1\neq M_2$.

As Asal Beag Dubh rightly remarked, more generally it suffices to take in $\mathbb{R}^2$ any three different 1-dimensional subspaces to obtain a counterexample of the result.